# adding arrows from-to positions in xskak

Tags: chess

I am trying to add arrows from-to positions in chessboard using the following code, but it did not work, how can this be done

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xskak, chessboard}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\getmovestyle[1]{%
\ifthenelse
  {\equal{#1}{N}}%knight move
  {\def\mymovestyle{[clockwise=false,style=knight]curvemove}}%
  {\ifthenelse
    {\equal{#1}{}}% castling
    {\def\mymovestyle{curvemove}}%
    {\def\mymovestyle{straightmove}}}}%

\newgame\longmoves

\mainline{1. d4}
\xskakloop{%
\getmovestyle{\xskakget{piecechar}}%
\[\chessboard[normalboard, 
 pgfstyle=\mymovestyle, color=blue!50,
  markmoves=\xskakget{move}, pgfshortenend=0.3em, arrow=to, coloremph, color=red!50, markstyle=circle, markfield=\xskakget{movefrom},
  emphfields=\xskakget{moveto}, setfen=\xskakget{nextfen}]\]
  }% End of \xskakloop...

\mainline{1... e6}
\xskakloop{%
\getmovestyle{\xskakget{piecechar}}%
\[\chessboard[normalboard, 
 pgfstyle=\mymovestyle, color=blue!50,
  markmoves=\xskakget{move}, pgfshortenend=0.3em, arrow=to, coloremph, color=red!50, markstyle=circle, markfield=\xskakget{movefrom},
  emphfields=\xskakget{moveto}, setfen=\xskakget{nextfen}]\]
  }% End of \xskakloop...

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must start a game with `\newchessgame` if you want to access the data provided by `xskak`. And don't ignore errors -- they indicate that something is wrong ...

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xskak, chessboard}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\getmovestyle[1]{%
\ifthenelse
  {\equal{#1}{N}}%knight move
  {\def\mymovestyle{[clockwise=false,style=knight]curvemove}}%
  {\ifthenelse
    {\equal{#1}{}}% castling
    {\def\mymovestyle{curvemove}}%
    {\def\mymovestyle{straightmove}}}}%

\newchessgame\longmoves

\mainline{1. d4}
\xskakloop{%
\getmovestyle{\xskakget{piecechar}}%
\[\chessboard[normalboard,
 pgfstyle=\mymovestyle, color=blue!50,
  markmoves=\xskakget{move}, pgfshortenend=0.3em, arrow=to, coloremph, color=red!50, markstyle=circle, markfield=\xskakget{movefrom},
  emphfields=\xskakget{moveto}, setfen=\xskakget{nextfen}]\]
  }% End of \xskakloop...

\mainline{1... e6}
\xskakloop{%
\getmovestyle{\xskakget{piecechar}}%
\[\chessboard[normalboard,
 pgfstyle=\mymovestyle, color=blue!50,
  markmoves=\xskakget{move}, pgfshortenend=0.3em, arrow=to, coloremph, color=red!50, markstyle=circle, markfield=\xskakget{movefrom},
  emphfields=\xskakget{moveto}, setfen=\xskakget{nextfen}]\]
  }% End of \xskakloop...

\end{document}
```

[image]